# Not able to find EditText resource by id in android studio using R class(Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am not able to retrieve the EditText elements using R 
This is my resource

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/goal_start_day"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/goal_start_day_title"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/goal_start_day_title"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/goal_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/goal_title" />
```

Trying to find element

```
R.id.goal_start_day
```

I am getting unresolved reference exception.However, I am able to find other elements from the same view but not 2 EditText elements I have

Comment: Did you try by Rebuilding the project? and also Invalidate Caches / Restart?

Comment: Please, post the code where you are using the id.

Comment: Please try this sequence: 
 1.    Build -> Make Project
2.    Build -> Rebuild Project
3.    File -> Invalidate caches / Restart

Answer (score 1):

try this one,

```
val goalStartDay= findViewById<EditText>(R.id.goal_start_day)
```

Otherwise you can also use `Kotlin Android Extensions`

Comment: thank you for the suggestion Ganesh. Unfortunately, this approach is giving me the same error